# Weird issue with "menus" Liquid object

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a question about object `menus` which is similar to `linklist`. It has a weird behavior.

Here is the code. Lines 6-9 contains 4 similar instructions to get menu from the `menus` object:

```
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
  {% if collection.handle == link.handle %}
    <p>test</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% assign linkTitleHandleize = link.title | handleize %}
  <p>menu[collection.handle] returns {{ menus[collection.handle] }}</p>
  <p>menu["bags"] returns {{ menus["bags"] }}</p>
  <p>menu[link.handle] returns {{ menus[link.handle] }}</p>
  <p>menu[linkTitleHandleize] returns {{ menus[linkTitleHandleize] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

So the html output is:

test

menu[collection.handle] returns EmptyDrop

menu["bags"] returns EmptyDrop

menu[link.handle] returns LinkListDrop

menu[linkTitleHandleize] returns LinkListDrop

For some reason, `menus` object returns expected "bags" menu array only when key is `link.handle` or transformed `link.title | handleize` (keep in mind that variable `linkTitleHandleize` is just a plain string) .

If I'm trying to pass same string but by `collection.handle` or even by plain string (in my case it is "bags") then `menus` returns nothing. I'm very confused, since the strings are equal (see condition on line 2 - it returns true and "test" is rendering) This is a very strange behavior and before this day I thought I know Liquid very well.

UPD: I have to rephrase my question. It is not about how to create a working version of code. It is a sort of research: why Liquid returns EmptyDrop for menu[collection.handle] and for menu["bags"] and why it returns LinkListDrop for menu[link.handle] and for menu[linkTitleHandleize] in case when linkTitleHandleize = link.handle = collection.handle = "bags". Thank you!

Comment: the linklist object is the "menu",
"linklist objects are called "menus" in the Navigation page of the Shopify admin."  -  [docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/linklist)  menus is just what linklist objects are referred to in the shopify admin ui

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw this reference in the Shopify official docs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `menus` object in liquid.

I don't know from where you got that object reference.

The code should be as follow.

```
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
  {% if collection.handle == link.handle %}
    <p>test</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% assign linkTitleHandleize = link.title | handleize %}
  <p>linklists[collection.handle] returns {{ linklists[collection.handle] }}</p>
  <p>linklists["bags"] returns {{ linklists["bags"] }}</p>
  <p>linklists[link.handle] returns {{ linklists[link.handle] }}</p>
  <p>linklists[linkTitleHandleize] returns {{ linklists[linkTitleHandleize] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Please note that it will return just `[Object]` since you are referring to https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/linklist

Comment: Actually Shopify referenced to it on the top of the article: "Tip
linklist objects are called "menus" in the Navigation page of the Shopify admin."

Comment: So, the main question is not about how to create a proper code (i know how to do). It is about how liquid engine/language works and why it outputs so weird array results for the same key.